# Implementar clase a partir de diagrama UML

Tags: java, poo, objeto

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y sé que es un tema muy básico pero se me ha pedido un ejercicio donde a partir de un contador, tengo que implementar una clase EjecutarContador por medio del método main donde necesito crear objetos como cont1 y cont2.

Y que me de como salida lo siguiente:

cont1: 3 cont2: 02
cont1: 3 cont2: 04
cont1: 4 cont2: 02

¿Como puedo realizarlo? Gracias!

(Anexo el diagrama de clase del contador igualmente)

[image: Contador]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Empecemos creando la clase `Contador` a partir del diagrama. El diagrama indica que la clase debe tener una propiedad privada llamada `cont` y tres métodos públicos que son: `reiniciar()` que retorna void, `obtCont()` que retorna int y `incr()` que retorna void. La implementación de la clase queda de la siguiente forma:

```
class Contador {
    
    private int cont;

    public void reiniciar() {
        cont = 0;
    }
    public int obtCont() {
        return cont;

    }
    public void incr() {
        cont++;
    }
}
```

Lo siguiente es crear la clase `EjecutarContador` que será la encargada de crear objetos de tipo `Contador` y manipularlos, la clase quedaría así:

```
public class EjecutarContador {

    public static void main(String...args {


        }
}
```

Dentro del método `main()` se crearan nuevos objetos de tipo contador y se manipularán de la siguiente manera:

```
public class EjecutarContador {
    public static void main(String...args) {

        // creación de un objeto Contador guardado en la variable c1
        Contador c1 = new Contador();
        // creación de un objeto Contador guardado en la variable c2
        Contador c2 = new Contador();

        // para incrementar el valor del contador se llama su método
        // público `incr()` el cual incrementa en una unidad el valor
        // del contador, como el valor inicial es 0 luego del incremento
        // el valor será de 1 
        c1.incr();

        // una nueva llamada al método hará que el contador valga 2
        c1.incr();

        // se hace el mismo proceso en el objeto c2, su valor inicial es de 0
        // luego de la llamada será 1
        c2.incr();
        
        // luego se imprime el valor de los contadores usando el método
        // obtCont() para obtener el valor actual del contador
        // el primer contador tendrá un valor de 2 ya que se incrementó 
        // dos veces
        System.out.println("El valor de contador 1 es " + c1.obtCont());
        // el segundo contador tendrá un valor de 1
        System.out.println("El valor de contador 2 es " + c2.obtCont());
        // luego se reinicia el valor de los contadores usando el método
        // reiniciar
        c1.reiniciar();
        c2.reiniciar();

        // al imprimir nuevamente los valores estos serán 0
        System.out.println("El valor de contador 1 es " + c1.obtCont());
        System.out.println("El valor de contador 2 es " + c2.obtCont());



    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Sueles entregar tu código sin comentarios útiles sobre lo que hace cada método o para qué se usa cada propiedad? Comentar el código es tan esencial como el código mismo. Por otro lado, ¿cómo responde esto a la pregunta del OP, y en qué lo beneficia? No lo tomes a mal, pero hay que tener cuidado en **NO** hacerle los deberes a los demás. Saludos

Comment: La persona que está aprendiendo cuando vea el código sin explicaciones es posible que le genere más dudas, o directamente que siga sin entenderlo.